# how to get the index of clicked element in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, button

I have a list and I want to navigate between questions by clicking on the element like in the picture [picture of elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2k7X.png) 
...[another usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fOPs.png)
I think if I can get the Text of clicked and convert it then use it as index it will work but idk how or if there is a better way to do it
thanks

```
List<Widget> _scoreTracker = [];
. 
.
.
_scoreTracker.add(
        answerScore
            ?
          GestureDetector(
                onTap: (){
                  if (endOfQuiz)
                    {

                     setState(() {
                       rev = true;
                       _questionIndex = **_scoreTrackerIndex;**

                     });
                    }
                },
                child: Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text("${_questionIndex+1}",
```

Comment: Can you include full widget

Comment: Can you include minimal full widget that will reproduce your issue, Sorry I am not getting from current snippet

Comment: you mean in code or in the picture ?

Comment: Code snippet  of full widget how and where you are using data

Comment: check the post picture please 
i only use it like this

Comment: Sorry I still failed to get it.   More about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: thanks for information , is it good like this ?

Comment: nope, ok you like to find index from `_scoreTracker`? You can include full scaffold

Comment: look i have as you see _scoreTracker is a list of buttons for example i want when i press any button of this list i want to return its index 
so can i get the index of clicked button from the list ?

Comment: you might find `_scoreTracker.length-1` is the index

Comment: if i use _scoreTracker.length-1 i got always the last button index
i want the index of the specific button

Comment: try below snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before `_scoreTracker.add(` line

do

```dart
final int btnIndex  = _scoreTracker.toList().length-1 ;

_scoreTracker.add(
        answerScore
       .....
        _questionIndex = btnIndex  ;
```

Comment: Glad to help, It would be better if you store value instead of widgets I think